# Convert String to Date object

Tags: java, date, formatting, string-formatting, simpledateformat

What is the preferred way to convert a string to a date in Java?

```
20151108235959 --> (15-Nov-08 11:59:59 PM)
```

Comment: you have to try something to know the best way?

Comment: thank you @codegasmer, 
i want to convert the string to date and then convert the date format

Comment: @MohammadKamel:  Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This should work as you specified in your question.**

```
  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss a");
  System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date()));
```

The date format you have in your question is something like:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHmmss");
```

Comment: thank you @intboolstring

Comment: Hey- if this helped you, could you mark it as accepted? @MohammadKamel